# Sass mixin default arguments, interpolation, quoting, etc. Compass box-shadow()

Tags: sass, compass-sass, mixins

I'm trying to do this mixin

```
@mixin dshadow($one: #{2px 3px 3px rgba(222,222,222, 0.3) false}, $two: #{-1px -1px 3px rgba(222,222,222, 0.3) false}){ 
@include box-shadow($one, $two);    
}
```

I've tried with and without interpolation, but I'm not getting it.  I get no shadow css at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop the `false`, then it works without interpolation.  Not sure why it's causing Sass to choke.  Color should be the last item in a box-shadow value anyway (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow)

```
@import "compass/css3/box-shadow";

@mixin dshadow($one: 2px 3px 3px rgba(222,222,222, 0.3), $two: -1px -1px 3px rgba(222,222,222, 0.3)) { 
    @include box-shadow($one, $two);    
}

.test {
    @include dshadow;
}
```

Generates:

```
.test {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.3), -1px -1px 3px rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.3), -1px -1px 3px rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.3), -1px -1px 3px rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, one issue seems to be I had an older Compass.  I upgraded, via Scout. (I am using phpsass, not ruby)  I got it working by hacking the box-shadow.scss:
  `$shadow : compact($shadow-1, $shadow-2, $shadow-3, $shadow-4, $shadow-5, $shadow-6, $shadow-7, $shadow-8, $shadow-9, $shadow-10);` to `$shadow: $shadow-1, $shadow-2;`  Not sure whats happening here, I dont find a reference to compact() in sass or compass site.  Without the hack, I was getting [css],[css],false,false,false,false so, obv, compact() was not doing what it should.

Comment: There are plenty of helper functions that aren't mentioned in the docs.  The `compact` function is written in Ruby:  https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/stable/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/lists.rb#L18

Comment: Yeah, I see that I have more issues coming, re: my use of phpsass.  Thanks for the help.